# How to put white space in-between integer values within a nested list?

Tags: python, string, list, formatting, whitespace

so I have a bunch of nested lists looking like this:

```
board = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

And I want to format the lists so that there is space in front of and after each individual 0. How can I do this without changing the 0 to a string? And if that's the only way, how do I change the string type 0's back into integers? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I don't have to change the actual list, this is purely for visual aid. I am actually printing out each row of the list row by row, so that it looks like:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: No, you can not do it! Do not do it!

Comment: This might be a XY problem. The data is always the same, no matter how it's formatted in a print or in your code.

Comment: I might have not gotten what I wanted to say out of my question, I need to print the whole list out row by row, is there any way to put the spaces between the 0's like that?

Comment: @MattyS11 is my answer not what you wanted?

Comment: It might be, its printing out each value of each list on its own line though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't do this with integers. There's no choice but to format it as a string, taking care of whitespace, line breaks and left-padding. In Python 2.x, do this:

```
for row in board:
    for n in row:
        print '{:>2}'.format(n),
    print
```

And in Python 3.x:

```
for row in board:
    for n in row:
        print('{:>2} '.format(n), end='')
    print()
```

*Do* notice that's for displaying purposes only, your logic must not depend on representing the board as a string. Use integers all the way, and only when needed, display them in the desired format.

Comment: this returns ( with values in place of  the 0's)   each value of the list on a line of its own. I can see this working, just need to modify it so that they each print on the same line, if they are in the same list

Comment: Yeah, i copy pasted. I'm using 3.6 and i used your second example. So i'm not exactly sure why its not working! haha

Comment: so now it prints the first element of the first list as a line on its own, then prints everything else. Also, my big issue is that if an integer of 10 or greater is anywhere in a row, it  pushes the spacing over so that the columns don't match up. If you don't see what i mean, just make a list like mine and make a column with a couple of single ints and then a double digit int.

Comment: @MattyS11 what do you mean? it's working correctly, [check it out](https://repl.it/repls/TerribleOutstandingKitty) online, hit the "run" button to see it in action.

Comment: see my edit, problems arise when there are values of 10 or greater.

Comment: @MattyS11 you really, really should state all the requirements in the question, we've been here what, half an hour? see my last edit, it'll add zeroes to the left of single-digit numbers. Really.

Comment: yeah, shitty on my part. sorry about that. Your method almost works. Is there a way to do that, except with whitespace in place of the 0's? thanks for all the help.                                                                                                            edit: I figured it out, it was just {:<5}.format_____. thanks for all the help man, really appreciate it.

Comment: @MattyS11 ok, my last update should do the trick. If you need more than two digits, adjust the number after the `>` sign. Phew. Ready to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer ;) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of adding whitespace to an integer without changing it to a string. The integer `0` embodies the concept of the number 0, with no information about its formatting.